# Which graphs solution for Drupal 7 can be used to upgrade my Open Flash Chart solution from Drupal 6?

Tags: 7, charts

I have upgraded from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and for me, everything is better in Drupal 7 until I hit this problem.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I have to create and show graphs to users depending on whatever the data they have stored on the site, I mean I have collected the data and stored in a Mysql database. I now have to fetch these data from that Mysql database and display it as a neat graph.

In drupal 6, making such dynamic graph is a cake walk..! I used [Charts and graphs](http://drupal.org/project/charts_graphs) module with "Open Flash Chart" to create some very interactive and pretty graphs. But it does not has a Drupal 7 version..!

**Attempting to use the 'Charts' module fails:**

Then I searched for one that could work in D7 and found the [charts](http://drupal.org/project/charts) module. It looked very promising and has a Drupal 7 version too. So I tried to install it, but I can simply not get it to work! I found a patch, but still no luck. Even if I get it to work, it will only work with Google Charts and not with Open Flash Charts or Fusion Charts because it requires those charts to be installed by us and Open Flash Charts or Fusion Charts, do not have a D7 version..!! FYI, the same problem existed in D6: when I installed everything (even Open Flash Chart API), it said "no chart plugin installed". And not even a single line of documentation is provided regarding how to install these plugins and make other charts work. Hence I think its out of the picture.

**My Question(s):** So what can I do now..?? How can I create graphs..? What can I use..??

**Update about this question**:

Since I didn't find any graphs module that I could use in my Drupal 7 site, I tried using an external PHP charting library "[pChart](http://www.pchart.net/)". I configured everything without getting any errors or warnings, but I only get a bizarre output ...

I have explained everything in detail, along with the code I have used to create the graph in my (new) question [What is causing the unusual output when trying to create charts in Drupal 7 using the pChart library?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23452/what-is-causing-the-unusual-output-when-trying-to-create-charts-in-drupal-7-usin) Any help to answer that new question would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [Views Dataviz](http://drupal.org/project/views_dataviz)? Here's a quick [how-to video](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/views-dataviz-module)

Comment: Well, thanks for your response. I finally, solved my problem by using fusion Charts free, http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/  . Views Dataviz really looks interesting as it would even work on iphone n ipad...! upvote for the suggestion..:)

Answer (score 1):

I've used highcharts script before, not with this module, but it might work for you http://drupal.org/project/highcharts

Comment: Hicharts, looks really cool.. but at the time I was looking for a graphs module, it lacked some good documentation I guess, am not sure though..:) Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

A few years later now, but the question seems still relevant. That's one of the reasons why I started my [Comparison of Charting Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985). Then I started working on [Chart 2.0](https://www.drupal.org/node/2368793) ...

Recently I extended the above mentioned comparison with [Maintenance Scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards) for all [Native Charting Modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#nativemodules). Consider using these scorecards to decide about using which "charting modules" these days.

Disclosure: I'm a (co-)maintainer of some of the charting modules mentioned,
I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contributions! I'm working on a project that we need quite many charts, and I considered to use chart module. But the API was somewhat unclear and coupled with the charting library (Google chart for example). We ended up inventing our own wheel, but I am more than happy to assist for a 2.x version.

Comment: Thank you Ayesh for your feedback. I can picture how you confused you were about chart, charts, Google-something-libs, etc (I still am a little bit too). To provide assistance, please look at "Chart 2.0" at https://www.drupal.org/node/2368793 ... or look at the "HowTo contribute" community pages of either Chart or Charts. And consider my hint above for the "funding" of bounties I want to start launching. Last but not least: the "chart"-deadline of April 2015 is getting close, but "my" solution for it also (can't give details on that right now yet, sorry).