# What is causing the unusual output when trying to create charts in Drupal 7 using the pChart library?

Tags: 7, charts

I have been trying to display graphs to users in my Drupal 7 website, by using the PHP library [pChart](http://www.pchart.net/)   (which comes with a lot of [documentation](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.introduction.html) also). Using the [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module, I have successfully enabled the pChart library.

Then I tried a basic example that came with the downloaded pChart library. Below is the code that I added in a node with the PHP filter enabled,

```
<?php
$name = "pChart2.1.3";
if ($path = libraries_get_path($name)) {
include($path.'/class/pData.class.php');
include($path.'/class/pDraw.class.php');
include($path.'/class/pImage.class.php');
}
/* Create your dataset object */
$myData = new pData();

/* Add data in your dataset */
$myData->addPoints(array(1,3,4,3,5));

/* Create a pChart object and associate your dataset */
$myPicture = new pImage(700,230,$myData);

/* Choose a nice font */
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>$path.'/fonts/Forgotte.ttf',"FontSize"=>11));

/* Define the boundaries of the graph area */
$myPicture->setGraphArea(60,40,670,190);

/* Draw the scale, keep everything automatic */
$myPicture->drawScale();

/* Draw the scale, keep everything automatic */
$myPicture->drawSplineChart();

/* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
$myPicture->autoOutput("pictures/example.basic.png");
?>
```

However, with no errors, warnings or notices, I only get the below unusual output:

[image: screenshot]

**My Question**: So what is this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are seeing is simply the PNG file that is being outputs it would be a text file. That is because Drupal already sets the "Content-type" header to "text/html; charset=utf-8," while the method you are calling is setting it to "image/png."

```
   function stroke($BrowserExpire=FALSE)
    {
     if ( $this->TransparentBackground ) {imagealphablending($this->Picture,false); imagesavealpha($this->Picture,true); }

     if ( $BrowserExpire )
      {
       header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
       header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
       header("Pragma: no-cache");
      }

     header('Content-type: image/png');
     imagepng($this->Picture);
    }

   /* Automatic output method based on the calling interface */
   function autoOutput($FileName="output.png")
    {
     if (php_sapi_name() == "cli")
      $this->Render($FileName);
     else
      $this->Stroke();
    }
```

What you could do is:

- Use pChart to create a file containing the chart you want to show
- Output a `<img>` tag that references the created file

If `imagepng()` used the PHP stream wrappers (which is true for [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)), the following code would work.

```
/* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
$uri = file_create_filename('example.basic.png', file_build_uri('pictures'));
$myPicture->Render($uri);
echo('<img src="' . file_create_url($uri) . '" />');
```

In this case, the code is slightly more complex.

```
/* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
$uri = file_create_filename('example.basic.png', file_build_uri('pictures'));
$instance = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri);
if ($filename = $instance->realpath()) {
  $myPicture->Render($filename);
  echo('<img src="' . file_create_url($uri) . '" />');
}
```

I wrote a conditional statement around `$filename = $instance->realpath()` because [DrupalLocalStreamWrapper::getLocalPath()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!stream_wrappers.inc/function/DrupalLocalStreamWrapper%3a%3agetLocalPath/7), the method called by DrupalLocalStreamWrapper::realpath(), can return `FALSE` when it cannot determinate the real path.

[file_create_filename()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_filename/7) is a function that returns a unique filename; in the case there is already a file with the name passed as argument, the function adds a number at the end of the filename, checking every time the file doesn't exist already. If "example.basic.png" is the name of an existing file, the function will try with "example.basic_0.png"; if there is already a file using that filename, it will try with "example.basic_1.png"; the loop is continued until the function find a filename that is not already used.

In the case you need to the filename to a function, as in this case, try first the `file_create_filename($filename, file_build_uri($directory))` approach, when you are not sure the function to which you are passing the filename is using PHP stream wrappers; only in the case it doesn't, you should use [file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri/7) as in the second snippet.